# Endpoint that returns CSV data is returning string with extra/unnecessary quotes around it

Tags: r, csv, plumber

We are using R's plumber library to create an API that returns data in CSV format. For some reason, one of the strings returned is being wrapped with quotes, and we cannot figure out how to resolve this. We have the following example code below:

**runapi.R**

```
# !/usr/bin/env Rscript
library(plumber)
pr <- plumber::plumb("endpoints.R")
pr$run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8004)
```

**endpoints.R**

```
#* @param season The season we want
#* @get /preseason-preds
#* @serializer csv list(type="text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
preseasonPreds <- function(res, season = 2023) {
  api_df <- readr::read_csv(file = 'data/our_csv.csv')
  return(api_df)
}
```

**data/our_csv.csv**

```
TeamID,FeedID
NASH,148048
LAFC,147671
PUNI,275
```

Output when we hit this endpoint:

[image]

The issue is the quotes around `NASH`. I am 99% sure there are no weird characters in this string. When we replace `NASH` with `NA`, or `NSH`, there are no quotes returned. The only other string where I could recreate the issue of getting these quotes is `NAS`.

What is it about `NASH`, `NAS` that results in quotes being returned around the string? It seems so random. Is there anyway to have the endpoint not return the quotes around this string?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Which version of the ‘readr’ package (that handles the CSV serialisation) do you have installed?

Comment: See https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/1386 & https://github.com/tidyverse/vroom/pull/436.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to latest `readr` version 2.1.4 has resolved the issue, we were previously using 2.1.2.